# Can´t find pptx module

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

when I import pptx I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'pptx'
```

is that an issue with python 3?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it

```
pip -U install pptx
```

It is not a standard Python package as far as I know

Comment: how do I install pip?